# Exported Constant not working in stylesheet

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

In one of the components in my project, I export a constant integer and then use it as a value for height in StyleSheet. In one particular case, it is not working and I can't figure out why. I have extracted the minimum possible code to reproduce it.

In `TopBar.js`, I export `NAVBAR_HEIGHT` and import it in both `Home.js` and `MyModal.js`. While it works right in `Home.js` when I use it as value of height in StyeSheet, it doesn't work in `MyModal.js`. However, if I replace `NAVBAR_HEIGHT` with a hardcoded int value, it works. It also works if I use NAVBAR_HEIGHT inline instead of creating a StyleSheet and passing the styles.topbar object.

(I wanted to make an rnplay for this, but looks like it can't make multiple files and thus, I couldn't reproduce it.)

Here is the code, apologies for making it long. I've also pushed it to [git here](https://bitbucket.org/gitanshu/rnheightbug).

Home.js (root component)

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

import TopBar, { NAVBAR_HEIGHT } from './TopBar';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { showModal: false };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.toggleModal}>
                <View style={styles.view}>
                    <TopBar showModal={this.state.showModal}
                        onClose={this.toggleModal} />
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }

    toggleModal = () => {
        this.setState({ showModal: !this.state.showModal });
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    view: {
        height: NAVBAR_HEIGHT,
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
    }
});
```

MyModal.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Modal,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

import { NAVBAR_HEIGHT } from './TopBar';

export default class MyModal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal animationType={'slide'}
        visible={this.props.visible}
        style={styles.container}
        onRequestClose={this.props.onClose}>
        <View style={styles.topbar}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{NAVBAR_HEIGHT}</Text>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  topbar: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    height: NAVBAR_HEIGHT,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20
  }
});
```

TopBar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Platform,
    Text,
} from 'react-native';

import MyModal from './MyModal';

export const NAVBAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 200 : 100;

export default class TopBar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>TEST</Text>
                <MyModal visible={this.props.showModal}
                    onClose={this.props.onClose} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
    },
});
```

I might be making some silly mistake but I have spent way too much time on this one and I'm still clueless. Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modules `TopBar.js` and `MyModal.js` have a circular dependency: TopBar imports MyModal, and MyModal imports TopBar. Because module resolution is synchronous, the imported value is `undefined`.

Extract the common dependency into its own module and reference it from both TopBar and MyModal.

Here's a simple reproduction:

**a.js**

```
import {b} from './b';
export const a = 'a';

console.log('A sees B as', b);
```

**b.js**

```
import {a} from './a';
export const b = 'b';

console.log('B sees A as', a);
```

**main.js**

```
import {a} from './a';
```

Outputs:

```
B sees A as undefined
A sees B as b
```

Comment: Ahh! This makes total sense. Thank you very much! :D